# What is this x86 inline assembly doing?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I came across this code and need to understand what it is doing. It just seems to be declaring two bytes and then doing nothing...

```
uint64_t x;
__asm__ __volatile__ (".byte 0x0f, 0x31" : "=A" (x));
```

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting.  It's been so long since I've looked at any of this, I'm not sure.  You might specify what assembler you are using.  I don't know if this is setting the content, the address, or both (!) of "x".  It wouldn't surprise me if x points at a memory mapped port, updated by a device asynchronously, and thus the "volatile" keyword.  Somebody who actually does this stuff will turn up soon, I suppose.

Comment: Bet you wish the original programmer used comments!

Comment: Easiest way: just compile it and then disassemble it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is generating two bytes (0F 31) directly into the code stream.  This is an RDTSC instruction, which reads the time-stamp counter into EDX:EAX, which will then be copied to the variable 'x' by the output constraint "=A"(x)

Comment: Ah ok!!  And the "=A" (x) syntax (I am using gcc4.1) to use %eax and %edx together - will it work on x86_64 arch? I think so but I dont know much about assembly.

Comment: Yes -- the 'A' constraint means a 64-bit value in the EDX:EAX register pair in both i386 and x86_64 gcc machine descriptions

Comment: @MK. and Chris:  No, in 64bit code a `uint64_t` given an `"=A"` constraint will actually just choose one of `rax` or `rdx`, like if you'd used `"=ad"`.  It doesn't split values into two equal halves for you :(  [This version that ORs together the low and high half](https://godbolt.org/g/nQfz7O) compiles to optimal code for -m32 and -m64, because in 32bit code the OR optimizes away.

Comment: @PeterCordes: It used to work in older versions of gcc, but I guess they broke the `A` constraint in more recent versions.

Answer (score 4):

0F 31 is the x86 opcode for the RDTSC (read time stamp counter) instruction; it places the value read into the EDX and EAX registers.

The _ _ asm__ directive isn't just declaring two bytes, it's placing inline assembly into the C code. Presumably, the program has a way of using the value in those registers immediately afterwards.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter

Answer (score 2):

It's inserting an 0F 31 opcode, which according to [this site](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html#x0F31) is:

```
0F 31   P1+   f2   RDTSC EAX EDX IA32_T...        Read Time-Stamp Counter
```

Then it is storing the result in the `x` variable

Answer (score 1):

It's inline asm [for `rdtsc`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/RDTSC.html), with the machine-code encoding written out to support really old assemblers that don't know the mnemonic.

Unfortunately, it only works correctly in 32bit code because `"=A"` doesn't split 64bit operands in half in 64bit code.  (The [gcc manual even uses `rdtsc` an an example to illustrate this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html))

The safe way to write this, which compiles to optimal code with gcc -m32 or -m64, is:

```
#include <stdint.h>
uint64_t timestamp_safe(void)
{
  unsigned long tsc_low, tsc_high;   // not uint32_t: saves a zero-extend for -m64 (but not x32 :/)
  asm volatile("rdtsc"  : "=d"(tsc_high), "=a" (tsc_low));
  return ((uint64_t)tsc_high << 32) | tsc_low;
}
```

In 32bit code, it's just `rdtsc`/`ret`, but in 64bit code it does the necessary shift/or to get both halves into `rax` for the return value.

See it on the [Godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-xc+-std%3Dgnu11+-fverbose-asm+-Wall+-Wextra+-O3+-m32',source:'%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0A//+only+works+in+32bit+code%0Auint64_t+timestamp_broken(void)+%7B%0A++uint64_t+retval%3B%0A++asm+volatile(%22rdtsc+++%23+output+constraint+expands+to+%250+%5Cn%22++:+%22%3DA%22+(retval))%3B%0A++return+retval%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+compiles+to+optimal+code+for+32+or+64bit+(except+with+gcc6.1)%0Auint64_t+timestamp_safe(void)%0A%7B%0A++unsigned+long+tsc_low,+tsc_high%3B+++//+not+uint32_t:+saves+a+zero-extend+for+-m64+(but+not+x32+:/)%0A++asm+volatile(%22rdtsc%22++:+%22%3Dd%22(tsc_high),+%22%3Da%22+(tsc_low))%3B%0A++return+((uint64_t)tsc_high+%3C%3C+32)+%7C+tsc_low%3B%0A%7D%0A')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3).